# Recover MS SQL Database from Azure

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, database-restore

By mistakenly i have delete few record from SQL database on azure, it is possible to recover from there, as azure take auto back of database, so its possible to recover.

Comment: With a restore, yes. The real lesson, however, is check your code before you run it in your production environment.

Comment: @Larnu Restore only allowing to restore from current database. no old data is there it has current deleted data. Is there any specific thing i have to do

Comment: Well you need to restore from a backup from *before* your error. It's no good restoring a backup from after it; that would include said error. If you don't have such a backup, the data is gone.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks you, Restored database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL Database has this amazing built-in feature to restore the database at any point of time to undo the unwanted changes made in the past or get the database back after mistakenly deleted.

The **Restore** option is available in **Overview** menu bar.

[image]

Fill the required details as shown in below image and click on **Review + create** option to restore the database.

[image]

Comment: Other users to know, Point-in-time restore (PITR) is depend on your pricing tier like: for basic plan it has 7 days and for standard it has 35 days. And for long-term retention (LTR) read (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/long-term-retention-overview)